# Animation in XNA

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I have this code:

```
        public class Area
{
    Texture2D point;
    Rectangle rect;
    SpriteBatch _sB;
    GameTimer _gt;
    int xo, yo, xt, yt;
    //List<Card> _cards;

    public Area(Texture2D point, SpriteBatch sB)
    {
        this.point = point;
        this._sB = sB;
        xt = 660;
        yt = 180;
        xo = 260;
        yo = 90;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(660, 180, 80, 120);
        spriteBatch.Draw(point, rect, Color.White);

        _gt = new GameTimer();
        _gt.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
        _gt.Draw += OnDraw;
    }

    private void OnDraw(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
    {
        this.pass(xo, yo);
        if (xo != xt) xo += (xt > xo) ? 10 : -10;
        if (yo != yt) yo += (yt > yo) ? 10 : -10;
    }

    public void pass(int x, int y)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 80, 120);
        _sB.Draw(point, rect, Color.Black);
    }
}
```

So, I can't understand what's wrong. And It's my first project with XNA, and because of it there can be stupid mistake :)

P.S. Sorry. There is a rectangle with coordinates (xt,yt), and I need the animation to move the rectangle to (xo,yo)

P.P.S. I added the full class with corrections, because I don't understand my mistake.

Comment: We can't understand what wrong either, since you do not explain what should happen and what happens instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are drawing the entire animation in one frame.. .you should call Pass with diferent x,y from OnDraw...

EDITED:

1) You don't need the timer, the draw method in game class is by default called 60 frames per second...

2) The Seconds parameter should be calculated as (float) gametime.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds;

```
float time;
int xt=660, yt=180;
int xo=260, yo=90;

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, float Seconds)
{
    rect = new Rectangle(660, 180, 80, 120);
    spriteBatch.Draw(point, rect, Color.White);

    this.pass(xo, yo, spriteBatch);
    time+= Seconds;
    if (time>0.3)
    {
        if (xo!=xt) xo+= (xt>xo) ? 10 : -10;
        if (yo!=yt) yo+= (yt>yo) ? 10 : -10;
        time = 0;
    }
}

public void pass(int x, int y, spritebatch sb)
{
    rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 80, 120);
    sb.Draw(point, rect, Color.Red);
}
```

As you should know this animation will move in a rough mode... if you want to move your sprite smoothly... you can use a Vector2 for your positions and a float for your speed;

```
Vector2 Origin = new Vector2(260, 90);
Vector2 Target = new Vector2(660, 180);
Vector2 Forward = Vector2.Normalize(Target-Source);
float Speed = 100; // Pixels per second
float Duration = (Target - Origin).Length() / Speed;
float Time = 0;

public void Update(float ElapsedSecondsPerFrame)
{
   if (Time<Duration)
   {
      Time+=Duration;
      if (Time > Duration) {
          Time = Duration;
          Origin = Target;
      }
      else Origin += Forward * Speed * ElapsedSecondsPerFrame;
   } 
}

public void Draw()
{
    rect = new Rectangle((int) Origin.X, (int) Origin.Y, 80, 120);
    sb.Draw(point, rect, Color.Red);   
}
```

Comment: That's right. Without just copy and pasting the code, however, you should try to identify the mistake in yours that Blau pointed out. In your pass function, you've just got a while loop going on that locks your code in.  Draw functions don't fire when you're stuck in a loop.

Comment: your code was full of design bugs... I have edited it to fix them, now it should run... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use Sprite Vortex to make your animations (a specific version actually) you can use the following class. You have to use Sprite Vortex 1.2.2 because in the newer versions the XML format is changed. Make sure that the XML file you add the property is changed to "Do not compile".

If you need a working example I can send you a very simple one.

p.s. Sprite Vortex should do the same thing you use the other program for, however v 1.2.2 is pretty buggy but not too bad.

the class is here : http://pastebin.com/sNSa7xgQ

Use Sprite Vortex (make sure it's 1.2.2) to select a spritesheet and select the sub images you want to animate. export the XML code.

add the class to your project, it reads the XML and adds automatically creates the frames for the animation for you.